# Mark OData Property as Nullable when using ADO.NET Data Services Toolkit

Tags: ado.net, wcf-data-services

We are using the [ADO.NET Data Service Provider Toolkit](http://www.odata.org/ecosystem) to implement a custom OData service endpoint running inside SharePoint 2010 (using .NET 3.5).

It appears that by default **Edm.DateTime is marked as Nullable="false"** when generating the metadata for the service endpoint:

```
<Property Name="DATE" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
```

Is there a way to change this setting for DateTime properties that can be NULL?

The same seems to be true for **Edm.Boolean** as well as some of the numeric types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of the property is Nullable, then so will the OData property.

In this case instead of DateTime, the property needs to be DateTime? (nullable).